# Boundary Condition at the segmentation

Tags: matlab

I have an image with three phases with different grey-values ( Black, Grey `[85 - 110]` and another grey `[115 - 148]` ). I get the segmentation between all phases but I have a boundary condition that has to be taken into account:

Between the black phase and the third phase there are some pixels (more than 5 pixels) with values of the second phase. I want to add these pixels to the third phase because they only appear due to a contrast change between the two phases (1 and 3).

The program is:

```
Bild1 = imread('croped0015.tif');
for j=1:size(Bild1,2)
    for l=1:size(Bild1,1)
        if max(Bild1(l:l+5,j))<85 && min(Bild1(l+5:l+10,j))> 123 && min(Bild1(l+10:l+15,j))<123
            Bild1(l+5:l+10,j)=min(Bild1(l+10:l+15,j));            
        end
        if max(Bild1(l:l+5,j))<123 && min(Bild1(l+5:l+10,j))> 123 && min(Bild1(l+10:l+15,j))<85
            Bild1(l+5:l+10,j)= min(Bild1(l:l+5,j));
        end
        if (l+16)>=size(Bild1,1) 
            break;
        end
end
end

imshow(Bild1)
impixelregion
```

How can I use a region growth algorithm for this?

[image: Example image]